# Dual Boot Ubuntu 12 and Windows 7 pro on two separate 3T hdd on uefi + bios mode

Tags: dual-boot

I have tried every solutions that have been posted by the "ask Ubuntu" site, and everyone of them is different - not necessarily different situation - in tackling my case. The answers are not organized and rather inconsistent. if you want to attract Linux users or help your community, then proper communication is important and keep in mind that not everyone has full knowledge and there are new members. Assuming everyone knows what you're talking about is WRONG.
So after weeks of wasting my time, I decided to join and share my problem:

My computer:

- Dell OptiPlex 9010 UEFI&Legacy (Core i7)
- 2 GPT converted HDs
  What I've done:
- installed Win7 first and then Ubuntu (with necessary partitions: /, boot, home, efi, swap,etc.)
- tried bootloader on both sda (windows) and sdb (Linux): didn't work
- on few occasions windows starts loading, but not Linux
- and on few occasion Linux booted and worked but not Window

THEN:

- tried to install the Windows while the second hd (for Linux) was disconnected from the board
  but same issue, Windows would boot, but not Linux
- tried to install the Linux while the second hd (for windows) was disconnected from the board, but same problem
- tried EasyBCD program from NeoSmart to set the bootloader when Window was running, but then I got the  error saying "there is no system boot, press F1 to retry, F2 for Bios setup or F5....."

So what is really a proper steps to implement this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Windows 7 default install is BIOS, did you convert to flash drive and make it an UEFI installer? If both systems are not installed in UEFI mode you can only boot from UEFI menu as BIOS/CSM and UEFI are not compatible.  Your method of disconnect drives should work. Post link to BootInfo report from this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Yes it's in UEFI mode otherwise I would not be able to use a 3TB hdd. You can only see over 3TB only if it's GPT and GPT can't be done unless the UEFI mode is enabled. So the problem, I think, is with Linux. What I really need is a proper steps from Linux group in which can be shared as UEFI becoming default on Windows.

Comment: Boot-Repair came to existent because steps provided are not consistent and people tends to screw up, results: Boot-Repair. We should not need the Boot-Repair if they're straight forward

Comment: We need to BootInfo report to know what is wrong. Generally installing separate works and Dell has been better than many other brands. It is the vendors that actually modify UEFI to only boot Windows that are the main issue. Originally grub2's os-prober did not find UEFI installs but that works just fine with 14.04. Most systems do not need Boot-Repair if standard UEFI install followed.

Comment: What is standard UEFI? could you elaborate on this? How would you do it? Steps?

Comment: Standard UEFI is one where vendor has not modified it to only boot Windows. That depends on brand of your system. And we need to know that and details of your install that the BootInfo report shows to know what to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps

- Backup your data
- Install Windows
- On 1st disk, create two partitions (1.5T,1.5T), On 2nd disk same as 1st disk
- Install ubuntu with / on 2nd partition, and /home on first partition on 2nd disk.

Ubuntu will install GRUB as primary bootloader, and it should add Windows in it. Backup your data, i'm not responsible for any data loss.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work: same issue. Conversion to GPT and installing both os goes well, but when you reboot, one of them runs and the other won't run. It's frustrating. I am not Linux Expert, but trying to have it installed so I can learn in depth, but first need to figure this one out. STEPS could be helpful...

Comment: What system boots?